# if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring Boot v2.6.2 and Spring Batch and getting below error:

> ustom destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'compositeItemWriter' threw an exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.xmlDelegateItemWriter': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope

MainApp.java

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.builder.CompositeItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.builder.StaxEventItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.*;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class CompositeItemWriterJobApplication {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> compositeWriterItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['customerFile']}") Resource inputFile) {

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Customer>()
                .name("compositeWriterItemReader")
                .resource(inputFile)
                .delimited()
                .names("firstName", "middleInitial", "lastName", "address", "city", "state", "zip", "email")
                .targetType(Customer.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    @StepScope
    public StaxEventItemWriter<Customer> xmlDelegateItemWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters['outputFile']}") Resource outputFile){
        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);

        XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAliases(aliases);
        marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

        return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .name("customerItemWriter")
                .resource(outputFile)
                .marshaller(marshaller)
                .rootTagName("customers")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> jdbcDelgateItemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {

        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .namedParametersJdbcTemplate(new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource))
                .sql("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (first_name, middle_initial, last_name, address, city, state, email) " +
                        "VALUES(:firstName,:middleInitial, :lastName, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :email)")
                .beanMapped()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter<Customer> compositeItemWriter() throws Exception {
        return new CompositeItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .delegates(Arrays.asList(xmlDelegateItemWriter(null),
                        jdbcDelgateItemWriter(null)))
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step compositeWriterStep() throws Exception {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("compositeWriterStep")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(10)
                .reader(compositeWriterItemReader(null))
                .writer(compositeItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job compositeWriterJob() throws Exception {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("compositeWriterJob")
                .start(compositeWriterStep())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompositeItemWriterJobApplication.class,
                "customerFile=/data/customer.csv",
                "outputFile=/output/customer.xml");
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>composite-item-writer-job</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>composite-item-writer-job</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Note: I also used `@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`, but no luck.

Bean

```
@Bean
    public org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope stepScope() {
        final StepScope stepScope = new org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope();
        stepScope.setAutoProxy(true);
        return stepScope;
    }
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  batch:
    initialize-schema: always
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: 'root'
    password: 'root'
    platform: mysql
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

**Things are still not working!**

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. For me, the solution was to add “@StepScope” on the methods calling the method with “@StepScope” and the jobParameters. In this example, I would try to annotate the method compositeItemWriter with “@StepScope”. You will probably need to do it with jdbcDelgateItemWriter.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public CompositeItemWriter<Customer> compositeItemWriter() throws Exception {
    return new CompositeItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
            .delegates(Arrays.asList(xmlDelegateItemWriter(null),
                    jdbcDelgateItemWriter(null)))
            .build();
}
```